# vuejs2 remove html node from slot

Tags: vuejs2

With the following code:

```
    <div id="app">
        <compo1>
            <div slot="firstname">test</div>
        </compo1>
    </div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'compo1':  {
                template: '<div><div>Custom Text</div><slot name="firstname"></slot></div>'
            }
    }
});
```

my components will be rendered like hereunder:

```
<div><div>Custom Text</div><div>test</div></div>
```

But instead of that I would like to generate this:

```
<div><div>Custom Text</div>test</div>
```

So it's the same code but here, the "div slot" is removed...

Comment: there is no way to do this unless you add a couple javascript logic and honestly it would be a bad idea to change it, you never know if something breaks. They are just divs and I see no need to remove one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<template>` instead of `<div>` in the parent while specifying the slot's content (`<template slot="firstname">test</template>`):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'compo1': {
      template: '<div><div>Custom Text</div><slot name="firstname"></slot></div>'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    out.innerText = 'Rendered: '+ this.$el.outerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <compo1>
    <template slot="firstname">test</template>
  </compo1>
</div>

<pre id="out"></pre>
```